# Why is cloning from github so slow

Tags: git

Pulling a repo from github and it is very, very slow and I can't work out why.

```
C:\projects>git clone --depth 1 git@github.com:sawilde/opencover.git
Cloning into 'opencover'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.255.112)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg........................................
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.255.112' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
remote: Enumerating objects: 1459, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1459/1459), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (829/829), done.
Receiving objects:  95% (1388/1459), 14.09 MiB | 8.00 KiB/s
```

I've tried a few things e.g. windows and ubuntu (via windows subsytem), full vs shallow clone, ssh vs https, ... etc, and I get the same slow behaviour; 30mins to get to 14MiB? I don't recall it being this bad.

Very frustrated as I get good speeds on general downloads and not sure why it is this slow to clone a repo...

Comment: I am not having any issues with my repositories, both ssh and https.

Comment: Try another repository, pull down the Angular source code or something.

Comment: I can download that repo very quickly. Diagnose this like any other Internet issue to a specific site. It's likely a routing problem between you and Github. A tool such as [mtr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTR_(software)) will help.

Comment: No-repro here too, cloned the same repo in about 10 seconds.

Comment: @AdrianBrand I did when I tried the `https://github-debug.com/` same again

Comment: @Schwern part of the test from `https://github-debug.com/` requests a ping and tracert - nothing immediately obvious to my eyes.

Comment: definitely seems something odd with my internet provider - tried via phone tethering and it was fast.


also checked the MTU and it is definitely under 1500 (i.e. 1472)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Likely a temporary routing issue on the service provider's end, but GitHub has a debug site where you can run a few tests and then send them the outputs for further investigation. The site can be found here:

https://github-debug.com/

Comment: It was the service provider but it took them a long time to identify the issue

Comment: Seriously ISP's should take this seriously. I'm cloning my critical repo at 18KB/s. Pain!

Comment: what was the issue? I am experiencing the same and can't get anywhere with AT&T :(

Answer (score 4):

Switching from using ssh to https did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Downloading the zip worked for me:

[image]