# Not able to clone into tensorflow models

Tags: git, git-clone

I am trying to clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git using git bash on windows, upon clone i get the following:

```
Cloning into 'models'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 81, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (81/81), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (62/62), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Tried cloning using both git bash and github desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried and clone successfully the GitHub repo (507.69 MiB to download...).

Try again, with:

- the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)
- a simplified PATH in a CMD

That is:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

If the issue persists, that could be a network issue, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55719020/6309) (you can try with https://github-debug.com/ for more trace).

The [OP njain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10137412/njain) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55719976/not-able-to-clone-into-tensorflow-models/55720104#comment98136521_55720104):

> I had forgot to restart the PC after setting up the new paths, I guess that was the reason: it's working now.

Comment: I updated git to latest version, tried cloning again but the network speed goes way down at around 14%, it then downloads upto 100MB or so, whilst the progress is still at 14%, then i get the same error

Comment: @njain Did you set the PATH as specified? And can you try cloning with https://github-debug.com/tensorflow/models.git?

Comment: i had forgot to restart the pc after setting up the new paths, i guess that was the reason, it's working now